# Dimple JS - Removing gap between the y-axis and the chart

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I am using dimple.v2.3.0 to create line and area chart. When creating chart with category x-axis, Dimple leaves a gap between the y-axis and the line/area. I would like to ask is there any way to remove the gap?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think it will be more helpful to us if you can share jsfiddle version, so we can go over your code.

Comment: This is the jsfiddle version [link](https://jsfiddle.net/sjnwLrbu/5/).Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't a good answer for this, it's done this way because dimple allows you to combine with bars etc.  There is a time axis for dates which will not include the gap and therefore answers the majority of cases with area charts, however categorical axes will always have the gap.

There is a hacky workaround you can use in this case where you have integers on your x axis which is to treat them as dates and put them on a time axis:

```
var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Call", "%Y", "%-Y");
x.timePeriod = d3.timeYear;
x.timeInterval = 1;
```

This will parse and display your calls as years and display them on the time axis.  The "%-Y" display format shows a 4 digit year with no leading zeroes.  This will work for integers up to 9999.  Here it is working in your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zuuaar1t/